# Angular 2 bind all style

Tags: css, angular, binding, styles

how can I bind a style when I don't know what is it ? I've a model with a string variable that define a style, for example:

```
myStyle1:string="margin-left:10px";
myStyle2:string="margin-right:5px";
```

how can bind these two variable to a div ?

**follow doesn't work:**

`<div [style]="myStyle1"></div> <div [style]="myStyle2"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge you can do like this

**HTML:**

```
<div [ngStyle]="myStyle1"></div> <div [ngStyle]="myStyle2"></div>
```

**Code:**

```
myStyle1={'margin-left':'10px'};
myStyle2={'margin-right':'5px'};
```

Answer (score 0):

That work, you need transform string to object and string must be json format.

```
<div [ngStyle]="myStyle1"></div> <div [ngStyle]="getStyle()"></div>


Style:string="{"margin-right":"10px"}";
getStyle(){
   return (JSON.parse(this.Style));
}
```